# Why Deletion between start and end strings won't work properly in java?

Tags: java

I have the following file that represent books

```
Book: ISBN=3
title=english1
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john]
-------------------------
Book: ISBN=5
title=english2
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john2]
-------------------------
Book: ISBN=6
title=english3
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john3]
-------------------------
```

I have tried to delete the second book from the file using this function:
the Funtion:

```
public static void removeLineFromFile(String file, String start, String end) {
    try {

      File inFile = new File(file);

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));    
      String line = null;
      Boolean flag=true;
      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.trim().equals(start)) {
         flag=false;  

        }
        if(line.trim().equals(end)){
         flag=true; 
        }

        if (flag && !(line.trim().equals(end))){
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
        }

      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the function call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       removeLineFromFile("E:\\file.txt", "Book: ISBN=5","-------------------------")
}
```

the book was deleted but the other "-------------------------" seperator are also deleted 
`

```
Book: ISBN=3
title=english1
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john]
Book: ISBN=6
title=english3
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john3]
```

What should I do to get the following result instead:

```
Book: ISBN=3
title=english1
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john]
-------------------------
Book: ISBN=6
title=english3
publishDate=1/12/2015
pageCount=200
authors=[12, 11, john3]
-------------------------
```

Comment: put it down on paper and check the condition - on 1st iteration flag is true and line is equal to end so it does not print in file ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I could come up with:

```
public static void removeLineFromFile(String file, String start, String end) {
    try {

      File inFile = new File(file);

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));    
      String line = null;
      Boolean flag=true;
      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.trim().equals(start)) {
         flag=false;  
        }

        if (flag){
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
        }

        if(line.trim().equals(end)){
             flag=true; 
             continue; 
            }

      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were setting the flag too early, and thus weren't printing the line out.

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is with this line:

```
if (flag && !(line.trim().equals(end)))
```

Since you have already checked if the current line equals your end String and changed the flag to true, this whole statement will always be true for every occurrence of the end String. Thats why every `-------------------------` line is not in the output.
If you remove the second part in this if statement means change it to: `if(flag){...}` you will achieve that every occurence of the end String will be in the output.

That leads to the second problem with your code: the order. You use a flag as a valve for your input to the output. You signal with your flag to turn off your output writing when found the start String. Then already check if you want to signal the turn on of the output writing. And only then you do your writing depending on the flag.
You need to change the order here to get a meaningful data stream.
Consider the two states

**The flag is TRUE means your stream should flow**

1. Check for start String
2. Write data

**The flag is FALSE means your stream should NOT flow**

1. Don't Write data
2. Check for end String

You can achieve the desired behavior with this while loop.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    if (line.trim().equals(start)) {
        flag=false;  
    }

    if (flag){
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
    }

    if(line.trim().equals(end)){
        flag=true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The second part of this expression is why your  "-------------------------"  get deleted (you never print the "end" lines) :

```
(flag && !(line.trim().equals(end)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of this.

```
if(line.trim().equals(end)){
    flag=true; 
}

if (flag && !(line.trim().equals(end))){
    pw.println(line);
    pw.flush();
}
```

In the first `if`, flag is set true, but the line `line.trim().equals(end)` is also true for this run in the loop, so the second if will never be visited when a line equals the variable `end` is reached. In this case it is the `-------------------`.

If your file looks always the same, you could change the loop to "when you find `start`, delete the next 5 lines", which is not really aesthetic, or you have to nest a new loop into the first `if`.

A nested loop could look like this:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().equals(start)) {
        while (!(line = br.readLine()).equals(end));
        line = br.readLine();
        // or you just write:
        // continue;
    }
    pw.println(line);
    pw.flush();
}
```

The second while would just go down till it finds the end and that continues.

Comment: Code which you propose doesn't delete one '----------------'.

Comment: You are right, then just add a `continue` or a new `readLine()` after the inner loop. NOT in the loop, after it! (will edit the answer)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the problem in terms of modes - you are either in copy mode or not.  If you are copying, then unless you find the start pattern you copy the input to the output.  If you do find the start pattern, then you switch to non-copy mode.

In non-copy mode you just look for the end pattern when you switch to copy mode.

In code terms, this becomes

```
  Boolean copyMode=true;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(copyMode) {
        // Check for signal to stop copying
        if(line.trim().equals(start)) {
            copyMode = false;
            continue;
        }
        // Just copy to output file
        pw.println(line);
    } else {
        // Check for signal to restart copying
        if(line.trim().equals(end)) {
            copyMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the updated code for this

```
public static void removeLineFromFile(String file, String start, String end) {
    try {

      File inFile = new File(file);

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));    
      String line = null;
      Boolean flag=false;
      Boolean skip=false;

      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (flag || line.trim().equals(start)) {
         flag=true;
         skip =true;

        }

            if (!skip) {
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();
            }

        if(flag && line.trim().equals(end)){
            flag=false;
            skip=false;
        }

      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note the introduction of a new flag **skip** This will help in excluding the content from Start  string to End string.

Comment: Where does `skip` differ from `flag`?

Comment: Neil, it doesn't differ,  skip  can be removed and  flag  can be used in its place.

Comment: The main point is when this flag should be enabled and disabled. It should be enabled when start string matches and disabled after end string is processed

Comment: My point is the that you only need to rename `flag`.  One of your booleans is redundant.

Comment: yes agreed , that's what I said in the previous comment

Answer (score 1):

This is simple solution with i came up it will remove every things b/w start and end strings but only when start string matches.

```
  Boolean flag1=true;
      Boolean flag2=true;
      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (flag1&&line.trim().equals(start)) {
         flag1=false;  

        }
        if(!flag1&&line.trim().equals(end)){
                flag2 = false; 
                 flag1=true;  
        }

        if (flag1&&flag2){
                pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();

        }
        if(!flag2) flag2=true;

      }
```

Note the introduction of a new flag1 and flag2 instead of flag.This will help in excluding the content from Start string to End string.